# EOFError: Ran out of input in Pickle

Tags: python, server, pickle

I am making an online game, but when I run it, it gives me a error for trying to send data to the server. Here is the code of the send command:

```
import socket
import pickle


class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "192.168.0.9"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.p = self.connect()

    def getP(self):
        return self.p

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

And here is the Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "client.py", line 148, in main
    n.send(btn.text)
  File "C:\Users\sande\Desktop\Vihaan\ThirdPartySoftware\Python\VisualStudiosCode\RPSOnline\network.py", line 26, in send
    return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Please can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In this code, you are making a common mistake that is often made when reading from a socket.  When you do a read from a socket with a call like:

```
self.client.recv(2048)
```

you have no way to know how much data you will receive.  All that you can be sure of is that you'll be getting at least one byte of data back, because the call will block until it can return some available data.  So you may not be reading all of your data.  Also, if your data is larger than 2048 bytes, you definitely won't be getting all of your data.

So it is not at all surprising that the line:

```
pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
```

would produce the error:

```
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

To know exactly what is going on, you need to look at the size of the data you
are sent, and the size of the data you are receiving.

The right way to do socket communication like this is to keep reading data until you know you have all of whatever it is you're reading. So you almost always want to read in a loop.  To know when to stop, you need to know when you have all of your data.  If the other side closes the socket after it has written all the data it is going to send, then you can read until you get an EOF.  If the socket will stay open, however, then you need to construct a protocol so that you know how much data is coming.  A common scheme here is to first send 2 or 4 bytes that tell you how many bytes will follow, and then send the data.  Then the receiver knows to read 2 or 4 bytes, turn that into a count, and then read that many bytes from the socket.

This is maybe more than you wanted hear, but I've explained this to a lot of people, and often it's something that really helps them.  The simpler way I can say it is "socket communication can be hard to do correctly".

Comment: @Viharo Could you select one of the solutions as the correct solution as well as marking your post as solved?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a fix to this problem. Steve is right, the best practice is to have a send function that sends information regarding the size of whatever you're trying to send, and subsequently sends the packet itself. Then in your receive function you first acquire the size of the incoming packet, then according to that size you keep receiving information until the full size of the packet is received.

I believe you followed the same online tutorial for sockets as my code uses the same functions coded in the exact same way. Therefore you should easily be able to use the functions in the answer that I wrote on my own question. See the following link for the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65383101/11239732